# Best way to store locale-translations for an webapp (with offline mode)?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, internationalization, nuxt.js

**WebApp Stack:** Nuxt.js with @nuxtjs/i18n, Express, Mongoose/MongoDB

Take into account that the webapp needs to work in offline mode so it needs to download content and translations or have them in the app-package and make packages for different langs.

Translations for general porpuses are stored in `/lang/<lang_code>.json`

**But how should I store my translations for the content?**

**Options I was thinking:**

- Store them in the database for each `/post{ title: { en-US: "Title", es-ES: "Titulo"}` inside the post data.
- Store them in `/lang/post/category/<slug|id>.json`
- Make separate databases and do `/api/es/post` (probably not a good idea)

Comment: Translations are already local no?

Comment: Yes, general translations (like header, footer components, report, about, contact page, etc)  are local!

Comment: Why do you not fetch them during build time ? I don't see the actual issue, can't you have them all static ?

Comment: So option two it's good enough?

Answer (score 1):

You can have your whole translations in a single file, per language. Of course, you can split it even further but having it static after build is totally fine and should be fine enough. And, if you are in need of an online solution, it's still the most simple and efficient one.

You can pretty much nest it as much as you can too. It depends of you need but having a 3k lines of translations is fine IMO. Just need some nice and organized structure.
[image]

[i18n-ally](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lokalise.i18n-ally) is an excellent VScode extension that may help you a lot with your i18n workflow. :)

Comment: Thank you, I think I'll probably have them locally as you said, I'll wait if someone else has some other feedback/tips/tricks. For general purposes translations (GUI) I have my lang json files like yours :)